# Fake book music. Why are there two lines of chords?

Tags: chords, sheet-music

I have a piece of music from a fake book which has two lines of chords above the melody.

Is the second line an alternative, or should it be played on the repeat?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the top line of chords is the standard, often the original. The alternatives are just that, alternative chord ideas, which usually give more scope to players and improvisers. Of course, the second line could be played later in the song, but usually a band will stick to one set or the other, perhaps even making subtle changes of their own. Maybe something like Eb, Cm for the first bar.

Comment: Way too early to say this is the preferred answer. Others may well come along that are better!  'Ain't Misbehaving'?

Comment: I doubt anyone could improve on that simple, correct answer.  But sure, let's see...